# change position module same panel dnn

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

if I add a second module in the left pane and want positioning them in DNN, I do what

2 examples I added html module in DNN left panel, the two modules stacked ranking now I want them to lie on the same line, they must change how

Answer (score 0):

You will need to place them in different content panels. By default module are placed 'on top' of each other with in a content pane.

Comment: need to have another container or get one of the 'wrapper' modules from snowcovered - http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=242&PackageID=19703&r=ccfe8cc709484a63b43f